# inheritance and sequence of initialization

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, initialization

Consider

```
 class A
   {
   };

 class B
   {
     B(A * in);
   };

 class C : public A
  {
    B b;
   public:
   C():b(this){}
  };
```

Is the constructor in `C` safe? Is member of `A` already available (and constructed) ?

Comment: Define "safe"..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes. All Base classes are constructed before the rest of the constructor is executed.

For example, from the Stroustrup C++ 2011 book:

```
17.2.3 Base and Member Destructors
Constructors and destructors interact correctly with class hierarchies (§3.2.4, Chapter 20). A constructor
builds a class object ‘‘from the bottom up’’:
[1] first, the constructor invokes its base class constructors,
[2] then, it invokes the member constructors, and
[3] finally, it executes its own body.
A destructor ‘‘tears down’’ an object in the reverse order:
[1] first, the destructor executes its own body,
[2] then, it invokes its member destructors, and
[3] finally, it inv okes its base class destructors.
```

Comment: Except for when `B`'s constructor tries to invoke a `virtual` function on `in`.